# Search functionality in listview android was not working?

Tags: android, listview, search

i want to make search functionality on my Listview, in my list it include listview image, listview Title and listview Description but i want to apply searching functionality on Title and description not on image, how is it possible?
Correct me, if i am wrong.... my adapter and search code is given below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_row_fellow_student,
      R.id.textView1, studentTitles) ;
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
   // Enabling Search Filter

     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MyFellowStudent.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);    
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
  class StudentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
        {
Context context;
String[] titleArray;
String[] descriptionArray;


int[] images;

StudentAdapter(Context c, String[] titles , int[] imgs , String[] desc) {
    super(c, R.layout.single_row_fellow_student, R.id.textView1, titles );
    this.context = c;
    this.images = imgs;
    this.titleArray = titles;
    this.descriptionArray = desc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           int textlength = cs.length();
           ArrayList<ContactStock> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<ContactStock>();
           for(ContactStock c: arraylist){
              if (textlength <= c.getName().length()) {
                 if (c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempArrayList.add(c);
                 }
              }
           }
           mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(activity, tempArrayList);
           lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the `afterTextChanged()`,

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (inputSearch.getText().length() != 0) {
      String searchText = inputSearch.getText().toString();
      setSearchResult(searchText);
   } else {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_row_fellow_student, R.id.textView1, studentTitles);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

and then,

```
public void setSearchResult(String searchText) {
   newSearchList = new ArrayList<MyFellowStudent>;
   for (MyFellowStudent info : list) {
      if (info.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
         newSearchList.add(info);
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_row_fellow_student, R.id.textView1, newSearchList);
      }
   }
}
```